# Is it possible to use a loop in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, regexextract

I have the following document:

```
+---+-----------+
|   | A         |
+---+-----------+
| 1 | Foo (100) |
| 2 | Bar (30)  |
| 3 | Baz (50)  |
+---+-----------+
```

I'd like to use a [`REGEXEXTRACT`](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=82712&hl=en&funcType=Text&query=REGEXEXTRACT&searchSyntaxExact=1) to extract the numbers from each row in column A and then total them. For example:

```
=SUM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+"), REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\d+"), REGEXEXTRACT(A3, "\d+"))
```

The problem is that this list will grow and for each row, I will need to make the formula even longer. Ideally I want a way to loop on all items such as:

```
=SUM_LOOP(A1:A3, REGEXEXTRACT(CELL, "\d+"))
```

... where the first argument is the range to loop over and `CELL` is the current cell in the loop.

I know that I can easily do this by creating a column to the right using a formula such as `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+")` and then expanding it downwards, and performing a SUM on this new column, but I would like to avoid creating a new column if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have row array with your values you can use this custom function to calculate the sum of the numbers (you can't use `REGEXEXTRACT` in the Script Editor, instead you have to use the JavaScript's `RegExp` function):

```
function sumLoop(v) {
  var sum = 0;

  for (var c = 0; c < v[0].length; c++) {
    var pattern = new RegExp("\\d+", "gi");  
    sum += parseFloat(pattern.exec(v[0][c]));
  } 

  return sum;
}​
```

For some reason if in the above function we'll ask for the number of rows (`v.length` as they mention in [Google Forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=591eeb9a405ebaef&hl=en)), it returns an error.

So in order to see it action do the following, after copying the above function in the Script Editor:

```
+---+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|   | A         |  B       | C        | D               |
+---+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+
| 1 | Foo (100) | Bar (30) | Baz (50) | =sumLoop(A1:C1) |
+---+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 19):

A kind of loop-like behavior can be achieved using array formulas. You can enter following formula:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B4;"\d+"))))
```

in a cell to have there computed the value you need in range you want.

Answer (score 6):

## Updated 2023 Answer

Now you can use functions like [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) and [`REDUCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597), which combined with [`LAMBDA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) allows for very powerful formulas.

[`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) cannot be exported, so my method has the advantage of being able to be exported.

An example formula for what you're trying to do would be:

```
= SUM(
  MAP(A1:A3, LAMBDA(val,
    VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(val, "\d+"))
  ))
)
```

I'm using vertical spacing and indentation to make it easier to read, but you can write it in one line if you wanted.

I also wrapped the `REGEXEXTRACT` with the [`VALUE(...)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220) so the string containing a number is transformed into a number.

You also mention having a new column with the numbers on its own, but you want to avoid it. I highly recommend having separate data in separate columns. The value `foo (123)` is a great example of separate data in the same column, so I'd recommend to split it in two if possible. It'll make working with any of that information much simpler.

Comment: Wait I'm confused... The advantage _over_ `ARRAYFORMULA` is that they _cannot_ be exported...? Is the ability to export a disadvantage?

Comment: @Matias The wording is a bit confusing, I agree. What I meant is that using ARRAYFORMULA prevents the spreadsheet from being exported, so the method I propose has the advantage that they can be exported. I'll rewrite that part so it's easier to understand. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the clarification (: